# {At / In} my friend's {house / home}?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was wondering which one is correct:

> I was at my friend's house.
>
> I was at my friend's home.
>
> I was in my friend's house.
>
> I was in my friend's home.

Which one is correct? Could you help me? If there are more choices, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, they're all fine.

In British English, I would suggest "at my friend's house" is the most common... whereas many Americans I know would probably say "at my friend's home".

I would normally only say "in my friend's house" if physically being in the house was particularly important, e.g. "I was in my friend's house when the ceiling fell in!"

Answer (score 7):

They are all correct, but there are subtle differences between them.

You're talking about the place where your friend lives. Wherever that may be, it is their ***home***. However, not everyone lives in a ***house***.

A ***house*** is a residential building. It can be a single-family house or an apartment house. But people also live in places like dormitories, hospitals, hotel rooms, campsites — even motor vehicles. So, if you were visiting someone who lives in such a setting, it might not be their house, but it would still be their ***home***.

When you use ***in***, instead of ***at***, you're saying that you're physically inside. If you're standing outside, then you're ***at***, but not ***in***. However, you can't be ***in***, unless you're also ***at***.

So, going through the examples you gave:

> - I was at my friend's house.

This says you were located where your friend lives, and that it is a residential building. It's possible you were also inside the structure.

> - I was at my friend's home.

This says you were located where your friend lives, but it's not necessarily a residential building. It's possible you were also inside the structure.

> - I was in my friend's house.

This says you were inside the structure where your friend lives, and that it is a residential building.

> - I was in my friend's home.

This says you were inside the place where your friend lives, but it's not necessarily a residential building.